# how to use couchbase as fifo queue

Tags: queue, couchbase, fifo

With Java client, how can I use couchbase to implement FIFO queue, thread safe? There can be many threads popping from the queue, and pushing into the queue. Each object in the queue is a string[].

Answer (score 4):

Couchbase doesn't have any built-in functionality for creating queues, but you can do that by yourself.

I'll explain how to do that in short example below.
I.e. we have queue with name `queue` and it will have items with names `item:<index>`. To implement queue you'll need to store your values with key like: `<queue_name>:item:<index>`, where index will be separate key `queue:index`, that you need to increment while pushing to queue, and decrement while popping.

In couchbase you could use increment and decrement operations to implement queue, because that operations are atomic and threadsafe.

So code of your push and pop functions will be like:

```
void push(string queue, string[] value){
  int index = couchbase.increment(queue + ':index');
  couchbase.set(queue + ':item:' + index, value);
}
string[] pop(string queue){
  int index = couchbase.get(queue + ':index');
  string[] result = couchbase.get(queue + ':item:' + index);
  couchbase.decrement(queue + ':index');
  return result;
}
```

Sorry for code, Ive used java and couchbase java client a long time ago. If now java client have callbacks, like nodejs client, you can rewrite that code to use callbacks. It will be better, I think.

Also you can add additional check into set operation - use `add` (in C# client it called `StoreMode.Add`) operation that will throw exception if item with given key has already exists. And you can catch that exception and call push function again for same arguments.

UPD: I'm sorry, it was too early in the morning, so I couldn't think clear.
For fifo, as @avsej said you'll need two counters: `queue:head` and `queue:tail`. So for fifo:

```
void push(string queue, string[] value){
  int index = couchbase.increment(queue + ':tail');
  couchbase.set(queue + ':item:' + index, value);
}
string[] pop(string queue){
  int index = couchbase.increment(queue + ':head') - 1;
  string[] result = couchbase.get(queue + ':item:' + index);
  return result;
}
```

Note: code can look slightly different depending on start values of `queue:tail` and `queue:head` (will it be zero or one or something else).

Also you can set some `max` value for counters, after reaching it, `queue:tail` and `queue:head` will be reseted to 0 (just to limit number of documents). Also you can set `expire` value to each document, if you actually need this.

Comment: Your code example shows the stack rather, but the same idea can be applied to fifo, with exception that it will need two indexes, like `queue + ':head'` and `queue + ':tail'` and on push it will increment tail, on pop it should decrement head

Comment: @m03geek that will be popping last inserted object every time?  [@]avsej but what value of head to use?

Comment: @twb Yes, it will pop last object.

Comment: I've updated answer. Looks correct for me. If it's not, please correct me, @avsej, because I don't understand why on pop it should decrement head...

Comment: I realized need to handle case where pop is faster than push. TTL is anything that will be used, thus need to handle as well.

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase already CouchbaseQueue data structure.

Example usage: taken from the below SDK documentation

```
Queue<String> shoppingList = new CouchbaseQueue<String>("queueDocId", collection, String.class, QueueOptions.queueOptions());
shoppingList.add("loaf of bread");
shoppingList.add("container of milk");
shoppingList.add("stick of butter");

// What does the JSON document look like?
System.out.println(collection.get("queueDocId").contentAsArray());
//=> ["stick of butter","container of milk","loaf of bread"]

String item;
while ((item = shoppingList.poll()) != null) {
  System.out.println(item);
  // => loaf of bread
  // => container of milk
  // => stick of butter
}

// What does the JSON document look like after draining the queue?
System.out.println(collection.get("queueDocId").contentAsArray());
//=> []
```

[Java SDK 3.1 CouchbaseQueue Doc](https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/current/ref/data-structures.html#couchbasequeue)